# Castle Windsor register interfaces and implementation from 2 different assemblies and namespaces

Tags: namespaces, inversion-of-control, castle-windsor, castle

I have 2 class libraries and 1 winform projects.

Class library project with namespace `IViews` contains all the interfaces declared.
Class library project with namespace `Views` contains all the implementation of those interfaces declared in `IViews`.

Now in WinForm project I am trying to configure Castle Windsor registration.
Note that all these 3 are different projects, namespaces and assemblies.

In registration I have written below code.

```
        WindsorContainer container = new WindsorContainer();

        container.Register(
            Classes.FromAssemblyContaining<IMainView>()
            .InSameNamespaceAs<frmMain>()
            .WithServiceDefaultInterfaces()
        );
```

And when I try to get the object for ILimitView by below line of code I am getting error as below. ILimitView interface is implemented by frmLimitView class in same project, assembly and namespace as of frmMain.

```
        container.Resolve<ILimitView>();
```

> Exception thrown: 'Castle.MicroKernel.ComponentNotFoundException' in Castle.Windsor.dll

For now I have registered individual interfaces and implementation line by line but it would be great if I could register them using assembly and namespace which contains all the interfaces and implementations.

Please could you throw some light here as what's going wrong in my code or provide an example on how it can be achieved?

Comment: It would be much easier to help you if posted the exception messages.

Comment: I have mentioned it in my question. I got error "Exception thrown: 'Castle.MicroKernel.ComponentNotFoundException' in Castle.Windsor.dll"

Comment: That's the exception type. There's a descriptive message that goes along with it.

Comment: My bad the message is "No component for supporting the service [Class Name] was found". I also tried in same assembly with 2 different namespaces but getting same error.

Comment: Well if you're only registering components `WithServiceDefaultInterfaces()` you obviously, by definition, won't have any services for classes. I'd suggest refreshing up on the concepts https://github.com/castleproject/Windsor/blob/master/docs/services-and-components.md and then reviewing your registration reflects your dependency graph. This will help you visualise it: https://github.com/castleproject/Windsor/blob/master/docs/debugger-views.md